# Where is the Tricross Sora front derailleur barrel adjuster

Tags: derailleur, shimano, adjustment-screw

It's supposed to be on the outer casing (according to the shimano manual) but the Tricross has internal cable routing.

Anyone know where it is? I really don't see it but I might be being a bit simple.

Comment: Have you looked for an inline adjuster? It looks like a bump somewhere in the cable housing. Usually between the bars and the frame

Comment: I'd look for an adjuster on the shifter or on the derailer.

Comment: It is on neither the shifter nor the derailleur. Would the inline adjuster be the seemingly useless piece of grey plastic that, in this case says jagwire on it?

Answer (score 3):

With out a photo it is hard to tell. Jagwire does make  inline adjusters. They have different types, that adjust differently. Check the Jagwire website or ask at the LBS where you got the bike for assistance.